# Sticky Footer not in correct place

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a multipage website and I'm including a navbar and a footer on each page, the navbar is in place and works just fine but my footer is all over the place. In some pages it's exactly where it should be, others it's in the middle of the page but it was like that before I even added page content.

I've tried a few things I found online but nothing's worked so far.
HTML:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navFooter.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table">
            <td style="border: none;"><p>Choose the type of comparison you'd like to make.</p></td>
            <td>
                <b>Quick Comparison</b><br>
                <a href="/a/comparisons?action=indicators&nid=100&nid=200&nid=300&nid=400&nid=500&nid=600&nid=700&nid=800&nid=900&nid=1000&nid=1100&nid=1200&nid=1300&nid=1400&nid=1500&nid=1600&nid=1700&nid=1800&nid=1900&nid=2000&nid=2100&nid=2200&nid=2300&nid=2400&nid=2500&nid=2600&nid=2700&nid=2800&nid=2900&nid=3000&nid=3100&nid=3200&nid=3300&nid=3400&nid=3400&nid=3500&nid=3600&nid=3700&nid=3800&nid=3900&nid=4000&nid=4100&nid=4200&nid=4300&nid=4400&nid=4500&nid=4600&nid=4600&nid=4700&nid=4800&nid=4900&nid=5000&nid=5100&nid=5200&nid=5300&nid=5400&nid=5500&nid=5600&nid=5700&nid=5800&nid=5900&nid=6000&nid=6100&nid=6200&nid=6300&nid=6400&nid=6500&nid=6600&nid=6700">Compare all counties</a><br>
                <b>Custom Comparison</b><br>
                <a href="/a/comparisons">Compare selected counties and/or jurisdictions only</a>
            </td>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){
            $("#navbar").load("navbar.html"); 
        });
        $(function(){
            $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body { 
    padding-top: 90px; 
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #19D8FF;
    padding: 25px;
    border-top: 4px solid #3399CC;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

Footer HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-left">
                <img src="img/Wordmark.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                    <a href="links.html">Links</a> |
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> |                    
                    <a href="apps/azindex.pl">A-Z Index</a> |
                    <a href="siteMap.html">Site Map</a> |
                    <a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                 <p class="muted pull-right">© 2017 All rights reserved</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I don't think this is it, but just a heads up, you have a random closing `</li>` tag in your footer.html file. Here: `<a href="disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a></li>`.

Comment: Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should put you in the right direction. I added bottom: 0 and changed the position to fixed. I also removed an uneeded

tag you had. This will put it at the absolute bottom of the view and always be fixed at the bottom.

```css
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body { 
    padding-top: 90px; 
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #19D8FF;
    padding: 25px;
    border-top: 4px solid #3399CC;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much!